# Pytorch - Conv1d followed by a Linear layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I have a task where I want to take an input containing some sequential data, feed them to a Conv1D + FC network and output a probability for each element in the temporal dimension of the input.

Essentially,

```
Input: (batch_size, num_channels, num_timesteps)
Output: (batch_size, num_timesteps)
```

My issue is that I have a ragged tensor, and thus I'm struggling to understand how I should do the transition between the convolutional and the fully connected layers.

```py
conv_layer = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=num_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same")
linear_layer = nn.Linear(what_should_be_here?, 20)
linear_layer = nn.Linear(20, 1)
```

I thought I could reshape my input array into having 32 channels before passing to the linear layer (`x.view(batch_size, -1, 32)`) but this ended up making the model not learn anything.

I understand I can replace the linear layers with a `Conv1d` layer with a kernel size of 1 but however I'm curious of what am I getting wrong here

Thanks a lot